# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No couch port for cache buckets

Tags: java, memcached, couchbase

If I try to create a couchbase client for a memcached bucket, I am getting this below exception.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No couch port for cache buckets
at com.couchbase.client.vbucket.config.CacheConfig.getCouchServers(CacheConfig.java:152)
at com.couchbase.client.CouchbaseClient.<init>(CouchbaseClient.java:232)
```

But if I change the bucket type to couchbase, its working fine.

I want to use Memcached bucket instead of couchbase. Please help.

Couchbase version = 2.0 and couchbase java sdk version = 1.1.dp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Michael Nitschinger said on #libcouchbase, this issue is going to be fixed soon. Here is the jira ticket http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/JCBC-121

Comment: I had posted it just before I got the reply. i will be waiting for the fix. thanks.